# git: add file history of other repository to existing file

Tags: git, version-control

I made a mistake and copied files from a git repository to a new one. The files were changed and I noticed too late that I lost the original file history.

Consider the example script below. It creates a file, modifies it and commits the changes to a git repository. The file is copied to another repository afterwards and changed again. As the file was just copied, the other repository doesn't know about the first one. Is there any way to restore its file history? Could that be done with a whole repository that is based on another one (including deleted files)?

```
#!/bin/bash
# create first repository
mkdir repo1 
cd repo1
git init
# create file and add it to git
echo foo > test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "init" test.txt
# update file and commit
echo bar >> test.txt
git commit -m "update" test.txt
# replace content and commit
echo baz > test.txt
git commit -m "replacement" test.txt
cd ..
# create new repository
mkdir repo2
cd repo2
git init
# get a copy of latest fileversion
cp ../repo1/test.txt .
# add it to new repository
git add test.txt
git commit -m "init 2" test.txt
# modify it
echo sometext >> test.txt
git commit -m "update 2" test.txt
# do some magic here to include
# the whole file history in the next commands result
git log -p test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First, git doesn't maintain "file history," it tracks the file names and contents as they change from one commit to the next. When you ask for file history, it is reconstructed (in some cases guessed) from the above.

You can copy the new files to the original repository, commit them there, and thus get the old history back. If you have new history on the new respository, you could ask `git format-patch` (see the manual page!) to create a series of patches to be applied with `git am` (again, refer to the manual!) to recreate the changes step by step.

Do such experiments on a scratch branch (or just a full copy of the repository), fooling around *could* damage it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! If I copied the new files back to the original repository, wouldn't I loose all changes that were made to the file in the new repository? I understand that you proposed to create patches that represent all file changes. Wouldn't I need to prepend those patches (prepend them before the initial commit took place)?

Comment: @muffel, applying the patches to the old repository replays the changes from the new one